# Updating user list on sub child event in Firebase Realtime Database in Android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to put the user on top in list when a message is added to any of child but the list remains unchanged insted of puting it up on top. [Please refer to this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1mx3.png) to understand it better. Thanks

Comment: can you explain why do you want to do this? the realtime database view always sorted alphabetically

Comment: I what the list to update like whats app list of user the one who send a text should be on top with some mark .

Comment: you can instead add another key to indicate if the message is read (new message) or not

Comment: But then i have to update it on every event to indicate that the grandchild is read so the will give a lot more complicated code.

Comment: Thanks for the help u at least took the initiative i appreciate mate . :)